# How to add IdentityModel reference

Tags: identityserver4

I am working through IS quickstart and having trouble adding IdentityModel to the Client project. I installed the NuGet package through VS.Net and it seemed to be successful but after that, the assembly does not show from the reference list. What am I missing here? Do I need to browse the file system to find the dll? If so, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the IdentityServer4 NuGet package, it has a dependency on IdentityModel. So it is already added and that's you don't see it.

You can see its dependencies [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/)

And in Visual Studio if you drill down the **Dependencies -> Packages -> IdentityServer4** node

[image]

Comment: I have IdentityServer4 package installed in my IdentityServer project but not in Client project. Do I also need it there? I thought that the Client didn't need the IdentityServer4 package, which is the entire identity server, and only needed the IdentityModel part which the client references.

Comment: No, you don't need to add IdentityServer for your client projects, if you try to add IdentityModel, perhaps some other package already have included it for you.

Comment: Thank you Tore! I finally get IdentityModel package installed in my Client. The only difference I am aware of is that this time I used the package manager, instead of the console, from VS installing it.